# does Ignite support read-through via REST API?

Tags: ignite

Ignite can be used to cache data from other databases.
When we request a value using the client, if this value is not in the cache, Ignite finds it in the database, returns it and stores it in the cache.
But when we request it through REST API and Ignite does not find the value in its cache, it simply returns null, and does not look for the value in the database.
Is there some setting to support read-through, when accessed via REST API, or it is supported only when accessed through clients?

does not find:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=get&key=33&cacheName=PersonCache&keyType=long&valueType=long
{"successStatus":0,"affinityNodeId":"33fa60c6-6dfe-4d3a-ae95-2c08c9e56f3f","sessionToken":null,"error":null,"response":null}

when accessed through the client, it does not find it, but pulls it up from the database:
java -jar ignite-loader.jar 127.0.0.1 PersonCache 33
Connected to Ignite on: 127.0.0.1
Connected to table: PersonCache
Cache size before operation: 2
Result query key 33 is a 3
Time elapsed query: 812
Cache size after operation: 3

and only now finds through api:
http://127.0.0.1:8080/ignite?cmd=get&key=33&cacheName=PersonCache&keyType=long&valueType=long
{"successStatus":0,"affinityNodeId":"33fa60c6-6dfe-4d3a-ae95-2c08c9e56f3f","sessionToken":null,"error":null,"response":"3"}

Comment: How can the key type be a long if the key is the string, "Mike"?

Comment: I'm sorry, I changed the IP and data, in fact, there are of course other values

Comment: How many nodes do you have? Does this outcome persist in case you directly request the affinity node of the key?

Comment: Now we use one node.
When we request using a Java client, the result is stored in the cache and can be obtained using the REST IP

Comment: It works for me, could you please share more details? What cache store do you use? Do you have a reproducer? What's your Ignite version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the bug in Ignite where `skipStore=true` is always applied for GET requests via REST regardless of the set options. I've filed a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-18094) for that.